# MySQL - How to use ROLLUP and ORDER BY in same query

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT donator, event, SUM(amount) AS total_donation_per_donator 
FROM tr_donation WHERE ngopkid=1 
GROUP BY donator, event WITH ROLLUP
```

Using above query I am getting below result.

```
Johnny Cruz
    Charity: Event 001 | Amount: US$ 100    
    Charity: Event 002 | Amount: US$  30    
    Charity: Event 003 | Amount: US$  90            
                         Total : US$ 220

Mike Polo
    Charity: Event 002 | Amount: US$ 200    
    Charity: Event 004 | Amount: US$ 125    
                         Total : US$ 325
```

Now I want to sort data by sub total of each donator (example: US$ 325, US$ 220) so donator with highest donation will display first.

Below query is sorting records in Ascending order but if I use DESC with 'total_donation_per_donator', it's sort all data in descending error witch is giving wrong result.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(amount) AS total_donation_per_donator 
    FROM tr_donation 
    WHERE ngopkid=1 
    GROUP BY donator, event 
    WITH ROLLUP
) 
temp_tr_donation ORDER BY total_donation_per_donator
```

Here is table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tr_donation` (
  `pkid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ngopkid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `donator` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `eventpkid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `event` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `amount` float unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `postdate` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: Yes, according to documentation, ROLLUP and ORDER BY can not be used together. That's why I tried 2nd query which is sorting records fine in ascending order but not in descending order.

Comment: Seeing as you've tagged this with PHP, if it was me, I would simply return a well-ordered result set and handle all the summary logic at the application level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    donation.`donator`,
    donation.`event`,
    SUM(donation.`amount`) AS total_donation_per_donator_and_event,
    sumdonation.total_donation_per_donator
FROM tr_donation AS donation
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        `donator`,
        SUM(`amount`) AS total_donation_per_donator
    FROM tr_donation
    GROUP BY `donator`
) AS sumdonation ON sumdonation.`donator` = donation.`donator`
GROUP BY
    donation.`donator`,
    donation.`event`
ORDER BY
    sumdonation.total_donation_per_donator DESC,
    donation.`event` ASC
```

You should test this query with a filled table before using it in production environment. Performance is possibly poor..

Comment: Thank you, query gives proper result and i needed to do some programming logic in PHP to display data in proper way.